# How do I convert an image to 24 bit?

Tags: depth, bit

How do I convert 16 bit depth image to 24 bit depth image. I already tried in photoshop as well,
Please suggest me how do I convert it.
Thank You,

Comment: Google "convert image depth photoshop"

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as a 24 bit depth image really in general usage. Each channel is 8 bits so any RGB image that's 8 bit would be... Red 8 bits + Green 8 bits + Blue 8 bits = 24 bits.

So if you're image is at 16 bit RGB say a raw file, just convert it to 8 bit RGB.

Answer (score -2):

In Photoshop select save for web, once the window pops up on the preset option select png-24, hope you find this useful

Comment: Please explain why that should help to solve the given issue ...